# Can you use Google Checkout as a simple payment receiver? IE. Without requring a full order?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, google-checkout

I am trying to integrate Google Checkout (as an extra alternative to PayPal) into my website to take simple payments. This payment is for allowing people into a website and not for a digital or physical item that will actually get sent.

Is this possible to do with Google Checkout, as whenever I get a payment from my "Buy Now" button, it creates an "Order" in my account which I then have to click "Ship" in my control panel for. I, of course, don't have an order to "ship" - the IPN (or API callback) does the hard work.

PayPal doesn't have this limitation, I can just take payments from people and process them in my database via their IPN - thus giving the user access - no PayPal intervention required, no clicking "Ship" anywhere. It doesn't seem to care if there are any items to be shipped.

Is there a way of achieving the same thing with Google Checkout (or can you do this simply with Google Wallet? What’s the difference between the two!?).

Any help regarding this would be hugely appreciated.

Thank-you kindly.

Answer (score 1):

Google Wallet/Checkout is not for person to person payments/money-transfer at this time. All their (Google) Payment APIs are based on the purchase of "something" - whether it be physical (shipped) or digital (dowload, app, game, etc.)

It's a not a limitation, it's what it is (at this time).